# Why is the form's onSubmit method not called when a DateTimeField is present?

Tags: java, html, wicket

A question regarding Apache Wicket: I have a form which contains several text input fields. It works fine until I add a DateTextField. The overriden method onSubmit() is simply not called anymore. I looked at the Wicket examples but cannot see a major difference to my code.

Here's the html code:

```html
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
 <head>
  <title>Students</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form id="createStudent" wicket:id="createStudent">
    <div>
     <span id="lastNameLabel"><wicket:message key="lastNameLabel" /></span>
     <input id="lastName" wicket:id="lastName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
     <span id="firstNameLabel"><wicket:message key="firstNameLabel" /></span>
     <input id="firstName" wicket:id="firstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
     <span id="dateOfBirthLabel"><wicket:message key="dateOfBirthLabel" /></span>
     <input id="dateOfBirth" wicket:id="dateOfBirth" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
     <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" wicket:message="value:submitLabel"/>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The corresponding java file:

```
package it.foo;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.datetime.StyleDateConverter;
import org.apache.wicket.datetime.markup.html.form.DateTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Button;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.model.CompoundPropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class CreateStudentForm extends Form<Student> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private DateTime dateOfBirth;

@SpringBean
StudentDao studentDao;

public CreateStudentForm(String id) {
    super(id);
    setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<>(this));
    add(new TextField<String>("lastName"));
    add(new TextField<String>("firstName"));

    final DateTextField dateOfBirthField = new DateTextField("dateOfBirth", new StyleDateConverter("S-", true)) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Locale getLocale() {
            return Session.get().getLocale();
        }
    };

    dateOfBirthField.setType(DateTime.class);
    add(dateOfBirthField);

}

@Override
protected void onSubmit() {
    // does not get called as soon as the DateTextField is present. Works fine otherwise. 
    Student student = new Student(this.lastName, this.firstName, this.dateOfBirth);
    studentDao.store(student);
    setResponsePage(StudentsPage.class);
}

}
```

I had a look at the html which is rendered in the browser. If the dateTextField is NOT present, it looks like this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Students</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form id="createStudent" method="post" action="./?2-1.IFormSubmitListener-createStudent"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="createStudent_hf_0" id="createStudent_hf_0" /></div>
    <div>
     <span id="lastNameLabel">Nachname: </span>
     <input id="lastName" type="text" value="" name="lastName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <span id="firstNameLabel">Vorname:</span>
     <input id="firstName" type="text" value="" name="firstName"/>
    </div>
     <!-- <div>
     <span id="dateOfBirthLabel"><wicket:message key="dateOfBirthLabel" /></span>
     <input id="dateOfBirth" wicket:id="dateOfBirth" type="text" />
    </div> -->
    <div>
     <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Schüler anlegen"/>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As soon as the dateTextField is present, the form has additional divisions with JavaScript calls.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Students</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <form id="createStudent" method="post" action="./?6-7.IFormSubmitListener-createStudent"><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="hidden" name="createStudent_hf_0" id="createStudent_hf_0" /></div><div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden"><input type="text" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off"/><input type="submit" tabindex="-1" name="p::submit" onclick=" var b=document.getElementById('submit'); if (b!=null&amp;&amp;b.onclick!=null&amp;&amp;typeof(b.onclick) != 'undefined') {  var r = Wicket.bind(b.onclick, b)(); if (r != false) b.click(); } else { b.click(); };  return false;"  /></div>
    <div>
     <span id="lastNameLabel">Nachname: </span>
     <input id="lastName" type="text" value="Matthias" name="lastName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <span id="firstNameLabel">Vorname:</span>
     <input id="firstName" type="text" value="Tonhäuser" name="firstName"/>
    </div>
     <div>
     <span id="dateOfBirthLabel">Geburtsdatum: </span>
     <input id="dateOfBirth" type="text" value="06.09.17" name="dateOfBirth"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Schüler anlegen" name="p::submit"/>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I don't quite understand why the additional divisions are there all off a sudden. My guess is that the JavaScript call does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a `feedback panel` and submit that will give you some idea whats going on ?

Comment: Wicket onSubmit is called after successful validation. You can check onError, maybe some problem exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the `onSubmit()` method does not call may be because of incorrect validation of dateField's value. You have to add `feedback panel` to you page and check .

Comment: You're right. I added a feedback panel and saw an error message that the entered value was in the wrong format for the DateTime.class. So my mistake was to set the wrong class for the DateTextField. It has to be: _dateOfBirthField.setType(Date.class);_

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onError(...)` method and look whats going on..

Comment: It will work even if you are not override the method also because it's form submit not `ajax submit` . I believe there must be a problem with date component which causing the trouble not showing since feedback panel not present